# PHP, JSON, and JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have done my reading, found no errors, but yet the php, json, and jquery are playing nice... can anyone see some thing I am not seeing here in this code for it not to work ?

My clickdates.php file has 3 values that json shpould make in 1 call... but it don't... Here is the php file (and when I test it, I do get 3 values and the 3 id's that should connect in the jquery).. Can you see something wrong that I don't ??

```
    <?php  
    $choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d"); 
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");  
    if (!$con)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }  
    mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  
    $sql = "SELECT sum(power/1000) AS choice FROM feed WHERE date = '".$choice."' group by date"; $res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $dayPowerP = array( $row['choice']);
    ?>
    <?php 
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("m",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("m"); $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");  
if (!$con)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  
$sql = "SELECT sum(power/1000) AS choice FROM feed WHERE month(date) = '".$choice."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$monthPowerP = array($row['choice']);
?>
<?php 
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("Y",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y"); $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");  
if (!$con)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  
$sql = "SELECT sum(power/1000) AS choice FROM feed WHERE year(date) = '".$choice."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$yearPowerP = array( $row['choice']);
?>    <?php
    $outarr['dayPowerP'] = $dayPowerP;
    $outarr['monthPowerP'] = $monthPowerP;
    $outarr['yearPowerP'] = $yearPowerP;
    echo json_encode($outarr);
    ?>
```

Here is what my test output is from the php file... in my eyes, it should work... but it don't.

```
{"dayPowerP":["12.7240"],"monthPowerP":["145.0460"],"yearPowerP":["941.0370"]}
```

Here is the very simple jquery that should be puting the values where they belong from the json... but no such luck...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {   
$('#datepicker').datepicker({maxDate: 0, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $('#apDiv1').html($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d', myDate));
            $('#apDiv5').html($.datepicker.formatDate('MM', myDate));
            $('#apDiv7').html($.datepicker.formatDate('yy', myDate));   
   $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",   
            url: "clickdates.php",                  
            data: {choice: dateText}, 
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function(json_data) {  
            $('#apDiv2').html(json_data['dayPowerP']); 
            $('#apDiv6').html(json_data['monthPowerP']);     
            $('#apDiv8').html(json_data['yearPowerP']); 

           } 
        })           
    }});
});
```

What am I not seeing here ??

Alan

Comment: Why are there square brackets around the numbers in the JSON output? That make it look like they are single entry JavaScript arrays rather than values. Can you load up a JavaScript debugger in your favorite browser and look at json_data after it' been returned to your AJAX response to check that out?

Comment: That is the live view in dreamweaver, to see if I have any output from the php file

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax is expecting valid json output witch the php file is not sending becouse you're not sending the right headers use

```
  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
  header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
  header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
  header("Pragma: no-cache" );
  header("Content-type: application/json");
  echo json_encode($outarr);
```

p.s. well ofcourse you need to change the dates

Comment: I am a bit confused, I send a date "Y-m-d" to the sql, but the return is a SUM value of data. not a date.

Comment: i wasn't refering to the sql but the header expiration , header last modified dates . sorry for confusing you .

Comment: I have been trying this, and reading more about the header, but my problem is still the same... When I just use jquery load or post and seperate php files, it works but too much time, and the ajax and json do nothing... I am lost